# How to get a discord member as a user?

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to grant someone a rank, but it says member doesn't have a reference to add a role.

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def grant(self, ctx, member, rank):
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace member with:

```
member: discord.Member
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that member is just like a default parameter. When you make it `member: discord.Member` as Boostio said above you will tell the API that it's about a discord member, rather than just a parameter called member.

So as Boostio said above change

```
async def grant(self, ctx, member, rank):
```

to

```
async def grant(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, rank):
```